# Convert an animated 3D model to Quake 2's models

Tags: animation, 3d, opengl-es-2.0, augmented-reality, quake

I'm about to create an Augmented Reality application which requires to render 3d models with animation. What is the best way/plug-in or software to export a model to old quake (.md2) format?

I want to use popular modelling software like 3Ds MAX, Maya or Blender. I have search all over the internet but I only found some plug-ins which I had difficulty to work with.

Any commercial tool? I need a good support.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hmmm... my favorite question.

It highly depends on what kind of animation you are willing to export.

**3Ds Max**
In `3Ds Max` there is an awesome plugin called [QTip](http://qtipplugin.com/). It only costs a few bucks but it's worth every single penny.

**Maya**
There is also another export plugin ([MD2Export](https://github.com/arifken/MD2Export)) for `Maya`. I didn't have much success with it but it's worth trying.

**Blender**
There are also some scripts written for `Blender` but none worked for me. But I think `Blender 2.46` has a native export for *MD2*.

**Stand-alone Software**
Few lightweight applications have a support for export *MD2*:

- [fragMOTION](http://www.fragmosoft.com/): Can import/export variety of formats and has support for *MD2* and *MD3*
- [MilkShape 3D](http://www.milkshape3d.com/): Same as `fragMOTION` but it also has an MD2 viewer which comes handy sometimes.
- [Quake2 Modeller](http://www.quake2.com/modeling/q2modeller/files/q2mdlr83.zip): It's very old and I didn't try it personally.

NOTE 1: As I said, it highly depends on your animation. If you have `Vertex` animation then `QTip` is your golden choice. `fragMOTION` and `MilkShape` do not support vertex animation. But if you make `Bone` animation, you may use the modeling software of your choice and import it to `fragMOTION` or `MilkShape` and then export it to MD2.

NOTE 2: I think you can find more information about MD2 [here](http://www.quake2.com/modeling/)